# Comparing a complete Magento (core) install to stock

Tags: magento-1.8, upgrade, ce-1.8.1.0

we have been upgrading Magento since 1.3 using Magento connect. Sometimes in a jiffy, sometimes with a lot of debugging. We are now @ 1.8.1. -> I have the idea though that not all files are of the latest release.

My question: is there a script or method to compare all core and base / default files of Magento on my server to a stock Magento 1.8.1?

Thanks

Comment: You can place a stock 1.8.1 in a directory next to it and run a diff between both directories. That should give you all the info about the differences between both environments. See the following link for more info about the usage of the diff command: http://www.rekk.de/bloggy/diff-command-overview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to find the difference is:

- Download Magento 1.8.1 release from Magento Commerce to some folder on your PC
- Copy the code of your working instance into another folder on your PC
- Download [DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/).
- Go to File -> Open File Diff
- Select original magento 1.8.1 release folder and your project folder
- Enjoy difference

Now you can find files which were missed during upgrade and copy them to your project folder using DiffMerge tool.

Comment: Both the windows and Linux prompt way work fine. I ended up using the Diffmerge solution, because I could easily click different files and investigate where the differences was found

Answer (score 4):

On any Linux based system, this is as simple as putting the stock install in a folder and running diff against the live folder and the comparison folder.

Major subfolders of concern are:

- app/code/core/
- app/design/frontend/base/
- js/
- lib/
- shell/
- skin/frontend/base/

cli command similar to this, check man pages for switches to narrow or expand your results.

`diff -rb --brief /pathto/testfolder/app/code/core/ /pathto/livefolder/app/code/core/`

to give you a list of changed files and files that exist in only one of the folder trees.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to compare database structure. This can be done easily (albeit crudely) like so:

```
mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-extended-insert -u root -p dbName1>file1.sql
mysqldump --skip-comments --skip-extended-insert -u root -p dbName2>file2.sql
diff file1.sql file2.sql > dbdiff.txt
```

read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases