# Recover part of a code from a backup file

Tags: admin, backend, backup

Pretty new to Magento.

After I made a **patch update** I got a problem in my **backend** with **editing my products**. I can press the **edit button** but unfortunately I does look **completely wrong**. I wonder if it would be possible to recover some files from my **backup** (tar.gz file) and upload these via FTP manager.

Best regards

Jesper

Comment: Yes its certainly possible to recover the respective files from your backup manually or you can just revert the patch. You can check the answer below, on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, just revert the patch that you installed using the command below, which will remove the changes made by the patch installed if you installed the patch through shell / command line.

> sh patch-file-name.sh -R

You can also manually revert the patch [as answered here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87141/695)

After that make sure to flush your cache completely by clearing the contents from var/cache/ directory

> rm -rf var/cache/*

If you use version control , just revert the commit after this patch.

Besides these, if you really want to know how to find the core files modified by the patch, you can use these options below:

[Comparing a complete Magento (core) install to stock](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16021/comparing-a-complete-magento-core-install-to-stock)

https://inchoo.net/magento/quickly-check-if-magento-core-files-are-modified/

[https://amasty.com/blog/freebie-magento-modified-core-files-report-by-amasty/](https://inchoo.net/magento/quickly-check-if-magento-core-files-are-modified/)